# SQL join on 4 tables not returning correct count

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariasql

I have 4 tables.

Sequences

```
id -> primary key
name 
user_id -> foreign key   (users id)
```

people:

```
id-> primary key
name-> varchar
seq_id -> foreign key from sequences
user_id -> foreign key from users
```

links_clicked:

```
id-> primary key
src_id -> foreign key (sequences id)
views -> Boolean
```

people_sequence

```
sequence_id-> foreign key   (sequences id)
people_id ->  foreign key   (people id)
```

I need to get the sequences details , count of link clicks from the link table , count of people if the seq_id is in there and count of sequences from the sequence from the people_sequence table.
I think I need to use the left joins and I wrote the query as below:

```
SELECT  sequences.*
       ,sum(link_clicked.view) as click_rate 
       ,count(people.seq_id) as prospect 
       ,count(people_sequences.sequence_id) as seqret 
FROM sequences 
LEFT JOIN link_clicked ON sequences.id=link_clicked.src_id 
LEFT JOIN people ON sequences.id=people.seq_id
LEFT JOIN people_sequences ON sequences.id=people_sequences.sequence_id
where sequences.user_id = 1
group by sequences.id
```

but this is returning the counts for each of the count column as same

Unable to figure out what is wrong with the SQL

```
id            | name |  user_id |click_rate |   prospect|seqret
5ac77be52d06e | seq1 |1         | 414       |    1890   | 1890
5ae790b48fea9 | seq2 |1         | 8         |    43     | 0
5ae790b6e0b12 | seq3 |1         | 2         |    0      | 0
5ae835c5153b5 | seq4 |1         | NULL      |    0      | 0
```

this is the result I am getting , but if I do the SQL the sum of views are different.and different for the counts also

```
SELECT `src_id` ,sum(`view`) FROM `link_clicked ` group by src_id

src_id         | sum(`view`)
5ac77be52d06e  | 23
5ae790b48fea9  | 8
5ae790b6e0b12  |2
```

Comment: give us sample data and what result you expect

Comment: Perhaps Count is not really what you're looking for in the query. 
Count is only affected by the WHERE condition.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ thanks! updated the question. Should I put in the results of the individual queries also

Comment: what i meant is give us sample data on the 4 tables.  I this way, we can double check if the sum, counts are correct based on our expectations

Comment: What are your expected results here?

Comment: @DanielMarcus need the correct count and sum of the columns that matches the sequence id

Comment: right im saying what are the correct results that you are expecting to see?  can you provide a  sample?

Comment: looks like you need to join people to people_sequences directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those left joins will send your results crazy ... you will get multiple repeat entries for everything as all the permutations of the joins are generated as results leading to nonsense sums/counts.  To see all the duplicate results, remove the aggregation and you'll get an extremely long repetitive and misleading list.  Try maybe 3 subqueries instead?

```
SELECT S.*
       ,(SELECT COUNT(IIF([view], 1, 0)) FROM link_clicked WHERE src_id=S.id) click_rate
       ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people WHERE seq_id=S.id) prospect
       ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people_sequences WHERE sequence_id=S.id) seqret
FROM sequences S
WHERE S.user_id=1;
```